# Spring mapping regular expression

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

I have a controller that needs to provide two GET implementations. 
The first returns a string and should be mapped to paths that look like this:

> /config/category/subCategory1/..../propertyValue

The second returns a map and should be mapped to paths the looked like this

> /config/category/subCategory1/..../subCategory4/

Basically the difference is that one path ends with a "/" and the other does not.  I've tried several options but none worked for multiple levels of subCategories.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Can you post what has been tried so far?

Comment: I don't know where to start with all the conceptual problems in this question. It seems you have it all wrong, its either you want to force spring to work with a malformed uri and/or don't want to use REST concepts like path parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern is easy, at least based on your very basic examples. You may want to remove the beginning `\/`.

```
\/config/([^\/]+)\/.+\/(.+)
```

I'm assuming `config/` is static, so we'll get that out of the way.. after that, we capture everything that is not a forward slash, which will stop when it encounters a forward slash. That's backreference #1. We add in a static forward slash, and then capture everything until the last forward slash, drop in a static forward slash, and then capture everything after the last forward slash all the way til the end of the string.

As for the second pattern

Let's say you have a category pattern like this

```
/config/Computers/Hardware/Storage/Hard_Drives
```

Regex is incapable of capturing infinite recursion as seperate variables, but you can capture as one variable like this

```
/config/([^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+)+
```

With the example above, backreference one would contain `Computers` and backreference 2 would contain `/Hardware/Storage/Hard_Drives`.

You can devise a regex like this

```
/config/([^\/]+)(?:\/([^\/]+))?(?:\/([^\/]+))?(?:\/([^\/]+))?(?:\/([^\/]+))?(?:\/([^\/]+))?
```

which would up to five levels deep.. and capture each category as its own backreference. If you needed to match for deeper than that, you could add another `(?:\/([^\/]+))?` to the end of the line.